# Remove Fabric missing dsym warning message without uploading the dsym

Tags: ios, xcode, crashlytics, dsym

I've accidentally caused a crash on Xcode build under the same version number of the production app, and now I have the following warning always showing on the dashboard:

> "Found x unsymbolicated crashes from missing dSYMs..."

My question is, in case I don't want to view those crashes, as they were self generated, is there a way that I can remove the warning message, without uploading the dsym, as I can't find the requested dsym using **mdfind**.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In Fabric the dSYMS are marked as “Required” or “Optional”, if the ones you're missing are required I don't think you can remove warning until the dSYMS are uploaded.

If you cannot find the dSYMS you can always download them from Xcode's Organizer or from iTunes Connect.

Take a look to these Fabric docs https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/missing-dsyms.html

Comment: That's in case we are talking about archived versions, or one's that were uploaded to itunes connect. Unfortunately the missing dSYM I'm having came from Xcode build, were I forgot to increase the version number, and even worse is after realizing the mistake, I've increased the version number without dealing with the new issue. I tried searching for dsyms in Xcode DerivedData folder, but didn't find a matching dsym, is my app doomed to have this warning for eternity?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the EXACT same issue. I don't have that dSYM file as it was not generated by Xcode due to the Build Settings I had...

Comment: Has there been any changes or we still can't get rid of the stupid warnings?

Answer (score 0):

One way you can deal with this is to disable Fabric collection for that app version. The downside, in my understanding, is you'll lose all Fabric reporting for that version, but if this crash report is for a years-old version that you don't have the symbols for any longer & don't care about reporting for that version, you can go to Settings > Apps > "Your App Name" > Versions and click through the pages until you find the version that ties with the crash report you see.  Flip the switch to off to disable collection.  It'll take some time for the dsyms for that version to no longer be marked as required (for us it took ~15 minutes, but I wouldn't be surprised if Fabric's system does this on a 24 hour basis & we got lucky) and eventually the warning you see in the Crashlytics tab will also disappear several hours after that.